# Unable to create a VM from captured azure image using ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to create an Azure windows image using Ansible as a part of my infra automation project. On executing the playbook every thing goes through:

[image]

My playbook looks something like this :

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  roles:
   - role: azure_vmcreator


- hosts: azure_vms
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
   - role: Generalize-windows



- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  roles: 
    - role: azure_imagecreator
```

There are two roles Generalize-windows and azure-imageCreator.

The generalize-windows.yml generalizes the windows from inside like this:

```
---
- name: sysprep windows
  win_shell: Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\Sysprep.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/generalize /oobe /reboot /quite'
```

where as the azure-imageCreator deallocates, generalize and capture the image :

```
- name: deallocate vm
  azure_rm_virtualmachine:
  resource_group: "{{ resource_group_vm }}"
  name: "{{ vm_name }}{{random_suffix}}-image"
  allocated: no


- name: Call REST API - VirtualMachines_Generalize
  azure_rm_resource:
     api_version: '2017-12-01'
     method: POST
     resource_group: "{{ resource_group_vm }}"
     provider: compute
     resource_type: virtualmachines
     resource_name: "{{ vm_name }}{{random_suffix}}"
     subresource:
       - type: generalize  

- name: Create an image from a virtual machine
  azure_rm_image:
    resource_group: "{{ resource_group_vm }}"
    os_type: Windows
    name: "{{ vm_name }}{{random_suffix}}-image"
    source: "{{ vm_name }}{{random_suffix}}"
```

now when i create an vm out of the image created by ansible i get below error:

```
"details": [
    {
      "code": "Conflict",
      "message": "{\r\n  \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n    \"details\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"code\": \"OSProvisioningClientError\",\r\n        \"message\": \"OS Provisioning for VM 'p' did not finish in the allotted time. However, the VM guest agent was detected running. This suggests the guest OS has not been properly prepared to be used as a VM image (with CreateOption=FromImage). To resolve this issue, either use the VHD as is with CreateOption=Attach or prepare it properly for use as an image:\\r\\n * Instructions for Windows: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-upload-image/ \\r\\n * Instructions for Linux: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/ \"\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone please tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: sorry, misread the question. are you generalizing a local vm or an azure vm?

Comment: well i am doing both and then creating a image, once the image is created i am create a vm out of it . on VM deployment i get the above mentioned error. Can you help me in understanding where i am going wrong?

Comment: Please don't post code snippets as screenshots, as it is hostile to searching and also explicitly mentioned as a no-no in the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In the future, please also format your YAML correctly, as its indentation matters

Comment: I am sorry for that i will correct it.

Comment: As 4c said, do you generalize the VM as this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource#generalize-the-windows-vm-using-sysprep) shows?

Comment: @CharlesXu yes i did that , if you look into my playbook there is a task which runs win_shell module to execute sysprep

Comment: How do you capture the image? And do you create the VM from the custom image or just from the generalized VM?

Comment: @charlesXu if you look into the above mentioned play book I use azure_rm_image module to create a image from the generalize Vm.. Once this image is created and you provision a vm using the created image, I get an error during deployment : the vm is not generalized properly

Comment: Well, I think the error shows the core info and it properly because that the ansible only executes the command and then turns on the next action, but the generalization needs some time to finish its work.

Comment: @charles Xu well i kept waiting for 30-45 and then took a image from the vm, it did not work

Comment: How do you wait? I mean the wait step. Do you try to manually generalize the VM as a test?

Comment: Well i added a wait module in playbook, on generalIzing the vm manually it works but that's not the goal, i need to automate this process.

Comment: I mean you could generalize the VM through the ansible task and then connect into the VM to check if the generalization works as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vinay, I had the same issue. 
The problem I was having was 3 fold. 
First is that the deallocation causes the Azure VM to change the powersteate to stopped. and the 'generalized: true' required the powerstate to  be running. 
Second was that that win_shell did not behave as I expected it (more reading for me to do on that) and that win_command recieved an error: "An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: InvalidCredentialsError: the specified credentials were rejected by the server." 
This was due to sysprep ending all connections to the server in order to generalize it. 
The 3rd is the wait time after the Sysprep has be run.

Once i realized that i needed to use /quit rather than /shutdown and that I needed to use win_command and that I needed a wait time, all was well. 
In the end it looks something like this. 
This is with ansible 2.8.6 BTW.

```
tasks:
  - name: "Sysprep VM"
    win_command: C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\Sysprep.exe /generalize /oobe /quiet /mode:vm /quit
    ignore_errors: True

  - name: "Sysprep Wait Time"
    pause:
      minutes: 5

  - name: "Generalize VM"
    delegate_to: localhost
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      name:           "{{ vmss_template_name }}"
      resource_group: "{{ resource_template_group }}"
      generalized:    true

  - name: "Check if VM is generalized"
    delegate_to: localhost
    azure_rm_virtualmachine_facts:
        resource_group: "{{ resource_template_group }}"
        name: "{{ vmss_template_name }}"
    register: generalized_output

  - assert:
      that: generalized_output.vms[0].power_state == 'generalized'

  - name: "Create Image from VM"
    delegate_to: localhost
    azure_rm_image:
      name:           "{{ vmss_template_name }}"
      resource_group: "{{ resource_template_group }}"
      source:         "{{ vmss_template_name }}"
```

In the end I'm sure there are more/better ways, but I'm fairly new to ansible and this worked for my POC. 
Hope this helps.

AA

Comment: I followed your steps but i was not able to deploy a new vm using the image created from Ansible steps

Answer (score 0):

@vinay, After VM deallocate, we need to wait for 3-4 mins for complete deallocation process. Once VM stopped, proceed with generalization.

Comment: so you suggest I should now generalize the vm from inside azure ? The generalize step in azure_virtualmachines will take care of it ??

Comment: Hi Vinay, I recently achieved this task, My steps are 1) Create VM (host is local host) 2)install applications on VM ( host is target VM) 3) sysprep, generalize and image out of that ( host is local host again because VM is in stopped state.  It looks like your issue with sysprep. try to use below command for sysprep.  
  win_command: C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\Sysprep.exe /generalize /oobe /shutdown.

Comment: Hi Bharat, I tried win_command but it is now working on my azure vm steup , on troubleshooting i found out that win_command should elevate it self in order to run sysprep . This is strange . Have you ever come across such thing before ?